# finding number of real solution of exponential and polynomial function

Tags: calculus

finding number of real solution of $f(x) = g(x)$, where $f(x) = 2017^x$ and $g(x) = x^{2017}$

Attempt: let $h(x) = 2017^x-x^{2017}$ and $h'(x) = 2017^x\ln (2017)-2017x^{2016}$

i am not be able to find monotonicity of $h(x)$ could some help me

Comment: consider only the two cases $x > 2017$ and $x < 2017$. The third case being easy to consider.

Answer (score 2):

May be, assuming $x>0$, it could be better to consider instead $$h(x)=\log(f(x))-\log(g(x))=x \log(2017)-2017\log(x)$$ and to look for the intersection of a straight line and a logarithmic function. $$h'(x)=\log(2017)-\frac{2017}x\qquad h''(x)=\frac{2017}{x^2}$$ The first derivative cancels at $$x_*=\frac{2017}{\log(2017) }\approx 265.068\qquad h(x_*)\approx -9237.83$$ and this point corresponds to a minimum (by the second derivative test). So, beside the trivial $x=2017$, there is another root $x$ such that $x<x_*$.

Since $h(1)=\log(2017)\approx 7.60937 $, we can try a Taylor expansion around $x=1$. This would give $$h(x)=\log (2017)+(x-1) (\log (2017)-2017)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$ Ignoring the high order terms, this would give as approximation  $$x\approx\frac{2017}{2017-\log (2017)}\approx 1.00379$$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

If you use Newton method starting with $x_0=1$, the successive iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1.0037869025620189051 \\
 2 & 1.0037941092023672378 \\
 3 & 1.0037941092283355056
\end{array}
\right)$$